# shrink width of button with animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I want to replicate this animation in my project

[image]

So what I did try is:

1. To transform scale X .. but the problem is it also shrinks the title of a button.

   ```
   self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
   UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delayTime,
                  usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
                  initialSpringVelocity: 0.7,
                  options: [.curveEaseIn],
                  animations: {
                   self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 1.0)
       }, completion: nil)
   ```

   This is what it gives (title of button also shrinks)

   [image]
2. Use of `CASpringAnimation`

   ```
   let shrinkAnim = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: "bounds.size.width")
   shrinkAnim.damping = 0.7
   shrinkAnim.initialVelocity = 0.7
   shrinkAnim.fromValue = frame.width
   shrinkAnim.toValue = width
   shrinkAnim.dura[![enter image description here][3]][3]tion = duration
   shrinkAnim.timingFunction = getTimingFunction(curve: curve)
   shrinkAnim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
   shrinkAnim.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
   layer.add(shrinkAnim, forKey: shrinkAnim.keyPath)
   ```

   So it can change the width but also position of the title
    [image]

So my question is whats going wrong or what I need to add to replicate first image?

> My constraints for button is pinned to left, right and bottom edges and fix height. and more thing is I am making a class for this so I cant change constants because I have to use this in many screens .. so I want one stop solution.

Comment: I think when we animate the views, we should remove constraints and set frames by code.

Comment: @RajanMaheshwari is it??? I don't really think so ..  may be you are right but I am not sure that we need to remove constraints for animations..

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `CGAffineTransform`, rather take and `NSLayoutConstraint` attribute outlet for Button's `width` and change its `constant` inside animation block/closure.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delayTime,
           usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
           initialSpringVelocity: 0.7,
           options: [.curveEaseIn],
           animations: {
            self.buttonWidthConstraint.constant = desired_width_here
}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: no sir I cant use constant .. check my constraints ... I am not using width constraint

Comment: Then you can just use your left contraint and right constraint and increase them inside UIView.animate block

Comment: UIView.animate { leftcontraint.constant = something; rightconstraint.constant = something }

Comment: @ZonilyJame the thing is I am making a class for this so I cant change constants because I have to use this in many screens  .. so I want one stop solution

Comment: Inside that class you could just set your max frame size (by the superview its put in) (or inside a UIView with a clear background) then calculate in that class how much distance you should remove on the left and right constraints. **Should I post that as an answer??**

Comment: @ZonilyJame Ok I'll try

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 I've posted it as an answer for further detailed explanation. you can look at it now

Answer (score 1):

Put your button inside a UIView

your view tree would then look like this

Superview > UIView > Button

By doing this you now have a fixed width size your button can follow which is the uiview

It would look like this

[image: View in a superview]

[image: Button Constraints]

[image: Left Contraint] [image: Right Constraint]

And then animate using

```
//let's say the current left and right constraint are 8

leftConstraint.constant = 50
rightConstraint.constant = 50
UIView.animate ... {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

By using this you'd only need to set the UIView's frame to your desired frame and have the button follow suit and your animations would just be set proportionate to how you'd code it

```
//let's say the current left and right constraint are 8

// get view frame

...

// calculate distance

var calculatedDistance = ......

// set distance
let distanceToAnimate = calculatedDistance

leftConstraint.constant = distanceToAnimate
rightConstraint.constant = distanceToAnimate
UIView.animate ... {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: this is good but as I said earlier to that I dont want to use constraint constants and 2 nd thing is just to change one button width use it as a subview of a view ... that I am against it and not to use it .. anyway thanx for your solution and your efforts

Comment: Fix your question then it's because of this statement that I thought you use NSLayoutConstraints **"My constraints for button is pinned to left, right and bottom edges and fix height."** 

goodluck though :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried content content hugging and compression resistance. Can you please try doing below at highest priorty. 
[image]

Comment: One more way you can try by adjusting font at the time of shrinking.             button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

Answer (score 0):

Apply the transform on the frame of the button. When you scale an UIView in animation it does not take consideration of subviews/layout it will just uniformly scale whatever is being drawn.

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delayTime,
               usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7,
               initialSpringVelocity: 0.7,
               options: [.curveEaseIn],
               animations: {
                self.frame = CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: If I need to set the frame than what is the reason of using auto layout??? may be I am wrong but setting a frame for change a width is not I want ..  and as I am making a class for this  and I have to use this in many screens, I want one stop solution

Comment: If you want do it with auto layouts then dont use left,right hugging constraints. Use self.width equals super.width proportionally. Then modify this width proportional constraint as a fraction of its original size in the animation.